# How to configure nginx in docker compose with .net angular mysql

Tags: .net, angular, nginx, docker-compose

I tried to configure nginx in docker compose.
Here are .net mysql angular images.
I believe I configured my nginx wrong. But i don't understand where.

here is docker compose.

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  datafiles:

services:

  database:

    image: mysql:8.0.22

    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

    volumes:
      - ./~mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

    restart: always

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}

  backend:

    image: image:03
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: always

    environment:
      - DBHOST=database
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

  frontend:

    image: image:00

    ports:
      - "4200:80"

    restart: always

  proxy:

    build:
      context: ./Proxy
      dockerfile: dockerfile

    ports:
      - "80:80/tcp"

    restart: always
```

In my local machine it is work. But if i try to up docker compose in my server. Nginx doesn't route.
I believe I configured my nginx wrong. But i don't understand where.

Here is nginx config

```
upstream front {
    server frontend;
}

upstream back {
    server backend;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://front;
    }

    location /graphql {
        proxy_pass http://back;
    }
}
```

Comment: It could happen that you are missing the ports in your container names? server frontend:80 same for the backend.

Comment: I tried so. But it does't help